# Excel VBA: How do I add text to a blank cell in a specific column then loop to the next blank cell and add text?

Tags: excel, vba

I need a macro to add text to blank cells in Column A. The macro needs to skip cells that have text. The macro needs to stop looping at the end of the data set.

I am trying to use an If Else statement, but I think I'm on the wrong track. My current, non-working code is below. Thank you so much - I'm still new to VBA

```vb
Sub ElseIfi()

For i = 2 To 100

If Worksheets("RawPayrollDump").Cells(2, 1).Value = "" Then
Worksheets("RawPayrollDump").Cells(2, 1).Value = "Administration"

Else if(not(worksheets("RawPayrollDump").cells(2,1).value="")) then 'go to next cell

End If

Next

    
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

To find the last row of data, use the `End(xlUp)` function.

Try this code. It replaces all empty cells in column A with *Administration*.

```
Sub ElseIfi()
    Set ws = Worksheets("RawPayrollDump")
    
    lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' last data row
        
    For i = 2 To lastrow  ' all rows until last data row
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = "" Then  ' column A, check if blank
           ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Administration"  ' set text
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to loop. Please try this code.

```
Sub FillBlanks()

    Dim Rng         As Range
    
    With Worksheets("RawPayrollDump")
        Set Rng = Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    End With
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Rng = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    If Err Then
        MsgBox "There are no blank cells" & vbCr & _
               "in the specified range.", _
               vbInformation, "Range " & Rng.Address(0, 0)
    Else
        Rng.Value = "Administration"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Assuming there is a value in cell `A1` (most probably the header), could (or even should) the `With` statement code be removed and the `Set Rng = Rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` line be replaced with `Set Rng = Worksheets("RawPayrollDump").Columns("A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` to include possible empty cells below the last cell in column `A` containing data? Consider the connection between `UsedRange` and `SpecialCells` (I noticed OP said something like `to the last cell containing data`).

Comment: I don't like to oblige the user to keep A1 non-blank so that my macro can run. The two subjects should be kept separate from each other. If blank cells at the bottom of column A should be included I would determine the last used row not by looking at the `UsedRange` but with a count in the more relevant column. More even than the use of A1 the *UsedRange* is subject to changes beyond the user's attention span while thinking of filling blank cells. Using it to determine which cells to fill would make the code less reliable and more difficult to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

### Replace Blanks feat. CurrentRegion

[Range.CurrentRegion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.currentregion)

- Since OP asked for *"... stop looping at the end of the data set. "*,
  I've written this `CurrentRegion` version.
- As I understand it, the *end of the data set* doesn't mean that there
  cannot be blank cells below the last cell containing data in column
  `A`.
- Use the 1st Sub to test the 2nd, the main Sub (`replaceBlanks`).
- Adjust the **const**ants including the **workbook** (in the 1st Sub) to fit your needs.
- `Criteria` is declared as Variant to allow other data types not just strings.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub testReplaceBlanks()
    
    Const wsName As String = "RawPayrollDump"
    Const FirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
    Const Criteria As Variant = "Administration"
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(wsName)
    replaceBlanks ws, FirstCellAddress, Criteria
    
End Sub

Sub replaceBlanks(Sheet As Worksheet, _
                  FirstCellAddress As String, _
                  Criteria As Variant)
    
' Define column range.
    
    Dim ColumnRange As Range
    Set ColumnRange = Intersect(Sheet.Range(FirstCellAddress).CurrentRegion, _
                                Sheet.Columns(Sheet.Range(FirstCellAddress) _
                                                   .Column))
    ' To remove the possibly included cells above the first cell:
    Set ColumnRange = Sheet.Range(Range(FirstCellAddress), _
                                  ColumnRange.Cells(ColumnRange.Cells.Count))
    ' Note that you can also use the addresses instead of the cell range
    ' objects in the previous line...
    'Set ColumnRange = sheet.Range(FirstCellAddress, _
                                  ColumnRange.Cells(ColumnRange.Cells.Count) _
                                             .Address)
    ' or a mixture of them.
    
' Write values from column range to array.
    
    Dim Data As Variant
    If ColumnRange.Cells.Count > 1 Then
        Data = ColumnRange.Value
    Else
        ReDim Data(1 To 1, 1 To 1): Data(1, 1) = ColumnRange.Value
    End If

' Modify array.
    
    Dim i As Long, k As Long
    For i = 1 To UBound(Data)
        If IsEmpty(Data(i, 1)) Then Data(i, 1) = Criteria: k = k + 1
    Next i
    
' Write modified array to column range.
    
    ' The following line is used when only the first cell is known...
    'Sheet.Range(FirstCellAddress).Resize(UBound(Data)).Value = Data
    ' ...but since the range is known and is the same size as the array,
    ' the following will do:
    ColumnRange.Value = Data
    
' Inform user.
    
    If k > 0 Then GoSub Success Else GoSub Fail
    
    Exit Sub
    
' Subroutines

Success:
    MsgBox "Wrote '" & Criteria & "' to " & k & " previously " _
         & "empty cell(s) in range '" & ColumnRange.Address & "'.", _
           vbInformation, "Success"
    Return
Fail:
    MsgBox "No empty cells in range '" & ColumnRange.Address & "'.", _
           vbExclamation, "Nothing Written"
    Return
           
End Sub
```